# Vue.js dynamic component reload

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue.js app where I use the `component`tag with `:is="currentView"` approach for changing the active view. I have a "state machine" that keeps track of valid transitions from a component to another component depending on some business logic. Sometimes this will tell the vue instance that the new value of `currentView`is the same as the old one. If this happens, the component will not be reloaded. Is there any way I can force the component to reload even if the view is the same? That is I want the data to be reloaded, and the lifecycle hooks being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick, hower it causes the view to flash, is there a way I can avoid this?

```
  const oldView = this.currentView
  this.currentView = engine.advance()
  if(this.currentView == oldView) {
    //force reload!
    this.currentView = ''
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      this.currentView = oldView
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a unique `key` attribute to your component definition so that it correctly triggers all the component lifecycle methods.

Your component definition should look something like this:

`<component :is="view" :key="unique_key"></component>`

**Helpful links:**

[Reloading a dynamic component](http://forum.vuejs.org/t/reloading-a-dynamic-component/10649)

[Vue 'key' api reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)

Comment: Please accept this answer. This is the correct way of doing it.